# Checking if attribute_changed? in ActiveModel::EachValidator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activemodel

I have a class Person that has first_name, middle_name, last_name.
I have a customed Each validator for these 3 attributes like so

```
validates :first_name, :middle_name, :last_name, nameValidator: true
```

In this validator I want to check if any one of these 3 attributes changed and given a few more conditions I'll validate name. For that I'm trying attribute_changed? but it doesn't work.

I've checked different methods from ActiveModel::Dirty and Activerecod::Dirty but nothing seems to work to check changes in each attribute.  What am I missing?

```
module Person
  class nameValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator

    def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
      return unless can_normalize?(record)
      #Normalization code 
    end

   def can_normalize?(record)
      anything_new = record.new_record? || attribute_changed?
   end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to check that some attribute was changed, you need to call `attribute_changed?` method on the record and pass this attribute like this

```rb
return unless record.new_record? || record.attribute_changed?(attribute)
```

Or may be use metaprogramming method like this

```rb
return unless record.new_record? || record.public_send("#{attribute}_changed?")
```

Some notes:

In Ruby we usually use PascalCase for class names and snake_case for hash keys

Validations are used for data validation, not for some normalization. It is usually used to add validation errors